# Outlook 2010 - disable contacts from other data file

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, contacts

In my MS Outlook 2010 I have my "Personal Folders" data file, and a secondary data file (.pst) opened. All fine.

However, under contacts I see the Contacts of my local Personal folders, as I do see the Contacts of the secondary pst file. While for calendars I can explicitly set which calendar to display, for contacts I can only arrange the search order (move up / down).

**How can I disable the search of contacts for the secondary data file?** It is disturbing to get them displayed, e.g when searching for email. Basically I only have opened the file to have its emails available.

-- Answer ppuschmann --

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this on a try:

- Right click on the 'contacts'-folder you'd like to disable
- Choose "Outlook-Addressbook"
- deselect the "use as addressbook"...

Of course Outlook has some special "*intelligence*"...

Comment: Do you mean the above (see screenshot in main question)?

Comment: Yes. Does it work to you?

Comment: Sorry, somehow missed to mark it.